# Blend in Visual Studio 2015 - No Design View

Tags: visual-studio-2015, blend

I am tying to build an app in Visual Studio 2015 in C# and I want to create a User Interface using Blend. But it shows me only the code in MainPage.xaml, not the graphic view. What should I do ? Here's how it looks

[image]

Comment: +1 here. My view is exactly same. Visual Studio 2015 Professional with uninstalled Win8.1 emulator and installed Win10 emulator.

Comment: @Minime did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to change the target version of the app to build 10240.
The default is set to build 10586, and the designer will not load.

Comment: This worked for me. I don't know why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: Worked for me. What a shame the issue exists 6+ months

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

- Close the editor on the page.
- Right-click on the HTML page to be editted in the "Solution Explorer".
- Select `Open With`.
- Find the entry `HTML (Web Forms) Editor` and click on it.
- (Optional) Click `Set as Default`.
- Click `OK`.
- Double click on the page to open it, and at the bottom of the IDE you will see `Design`, `Split` and `Source`.
- Click on `Design`.

Comment: Genius. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response and potential solution, but I figure it's good to record the solution I found. I ran into this problem as well (with a VB project). The problem was caused when I put in a label on the form, and then I got some weird error... I told VS (2015 Community) to ignore the error as I was going to remove the element anyway... but in the process, VS decided to break the Form1.vb file completely (it was blanked out) and SAVE it when I never told it to do so...

The solution was to manually edit the Form1.vb file and restore what was supposed to be in there, which in my case was simply:

`Public Class Form1
End Class`

After making this edit manually, I was able to reopen the project and the "Design view" was available again (via right-click). Again, not sure why VS decided to save over my working program after it caught some error (that's the LAST thing you'd want to do when you get an error!) but I guess that just means I'll need to be more careful and make backups as I program to work around that crazy behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Switch between Design, Code, and Split views by pressing F11
According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170161.aspx

If that doesn't work try Shift-f7 or right click the file in solution explorer and choose View Designer

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked. By pressing F11 it only Debug the app