# Making HTML/WinJS App in VS2015, No Design / Split View

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, winjs

I've tried this multiple times and following directions on how to get Design view available from all across the internet, but I'm having no luck.

Here's the full details: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I make a new project, Templates > Javascript > Windows > Universal > WinJS App. I've set html files to open with HTML Web Forms Editor by default, I've enabled it in Tools > Options, but still at the bottom of the HTML editor panel, only Sources is available.

I'm coming from VS2013 where I got quite comfortable with using Blend for my HTML windows store projects. I was saddened to find out Blend 2015 doesn't support WinJS projects anymore, but I read that Visual Studio has put a lot of work into HTML/CSS editing within VS itself -- that's great! But I can't access it :(

This isn't a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917804/blend-in-visual-studio-2015-no-design-view), as that's for C# and I've tried all of the applicable advice on that question anyway, it hasn't worked. I can open design view in C#, so I think it's a WinJS / HTML problem specifically.

Answer (score 0):

From Blend for Visual Studio 2015, HTML5/JavaScript based app support has been [dropped](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6959166-support-for-html-js-apps-in-blend-for-visual-studi).

That is, you cannot use Blend to design HTML5/JavaScript based UWP App anymore. You can still use DOM Explorer's CSS Editor for live view of your app's design while you're in debugging mode.